# Node.js prompt '>' can not show in eshell

Tags: node.js, emacs, eshell

I want to run Node.js in eshell, but the prompt does not right:

[image]

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Those look like terminal control codes. Maybe try running in an `ansi-term' instead?

Comment: Use bash/zsh in emacs and run node is ok. But I want to try node repl in eshell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running node in eshell with `NODE_NO_READLINE` enabled. For example, you could add an alias to eshell by running this command in eshell:

```
alias node 'NODE_NO_READLINE=1 node'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me using Node v0.10.8 in Emacs 24.3.50.1 (2013-05-29) where my eshell is sending commands to a remote machine over TRAMP.

Comment: Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is to add this to your .emacs:

(setenv "NODE_NO_READLINE" "1")

The benefit of this approach is that it will also work for other invocations of Node programs that you run directly.