# Using Node.js with JS-comint in Emacs

Tags: node.js, emacs, read-eval-print-loop, js2-mode

I use Emacs 24.2. I've installed `js-comint` and `js-mode` from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/), executed `run-js`, and now in REPL instead of `>` sign i have this gibberish:

```
^[[1G> ^[[0K^[[3G
```

The REPL itself in Inferior Javascript mode works just fine, just the `>` sign is changed. If you enter unfinished expression, it even prints `^[[1G... ^[[0K^[[5G`. The `^[` are system characters, that are not copied with copy-paste, i add them for you to have an idea.

In my init-file:

```
(require 'js-comint)
(setq inferior-js-program-command "nodejs")
```

In terminal calling `nodejs` produces working REPL.

Why prompt behaves this way? What should i do to correct this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
(setq inferior-js-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; We like nice colors
        (ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
        ;; Deal with some prompt nonsense
        (add-to-list
         'comint-preoutput-filter-functions
         (lambda (output)
           (replace-regexp-in-string "\033\\[[0-9]+[GK]" "" output)))))
```

`\033` is the escape character it prints as `^[`.

Comment: but why does prompt produce garbage?

Comment: Made a minor edit to the last statement:
`(replace-regexp-in-string "\033\\[[0-9]+[A-Z]" "" output)))))`

Answer (score 20):

Just add one line in your .emacs:

```
(setenv "NODE_NO_READLINE" "1")
```

Answer come from this post:
[Node.js prompt '>' can not show in eshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390770/node-js-prompt-can-not-show-in-eshell)

Comment: +1.  this basically worked for me, thanks.  I created a file named 'repl' in my app directory, and in it put NODE_NO_READLINE=1 node.  Then just call ./repl from within an emacs shell and you get a node repl inside emacs with correct module scoping and no output giberrish.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how recent, but now one can download and use the `nodejs-repl`.