# In Emacs nodejs mode get garbage prompt

Tags: node.js, shell, emacs, read-eval-print-loop

I use `nodejs-mode` on `Emacs 24`, But when i type:

```
M-x nodejs
```

it prompt garbage prompts like `[0J>`, now even though i have added below

```
(setq ansi-color-for-comint-mode t)
```

in `emacs` file. It still not work.

all the same, if i type `node` directory on `Emacs shell-mode`, then I will got an more annoying prompt like below:

```
ryu@ryu:~$ node
[1G[0J> [3G
```

Does any know why it behave like this?

Answer (score 1):

finally i give up using nodejs-mode for the interactive. then refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862471/using-node-js-with-js-comint-in-emacs)