# Emacs M-x term can't find node/coffee

Tags: node.js, bash, emacs

I've been plonking around on mac-emacs, and I've `M-x install-package`-d coffee-mode. I decided to try out the `coffee-compile-file` command, but when I ran it, it failed, complaining that it couldn't find the `coffee` command.

So, I open up terminal, on ZSH and Bash. `coffee` and `node` run fine on both. So, split my emacs screen, plink out `M-x term`, let bash load, and type `coffee`:

```
bash-3.2$ coffee 
bash: coffee: command not found
```

Odd. I tried the same for node and npm.

```
bash-3.2$ node
bash: node: command not found
bash-3.2$ npm
bash: npm: command not found
```

My question is, *why* does this happen only on `M-x term`, and how can I fix it.

Comment: Presumably you set up paths and things during shell init and that isn't happening for `M-x term`. Where did you set those up?

Comment: @Etan Reisner I checked `.zshrc` and `.bashrc`, but there's nothing referring to `node` or `coffee`, only `rhino` and `clojure`.

Comment: Perhaps you are using different shell interpreters.

When you run `M-x term` Emacs asks for you to pick the interpreter. Check if you are using the same in the console outside Emacs. To do so, simply type `ps` on the terminal.

Comment: What does `which coffee` output (where `coffee` works)? Is `$PATH` different in the emacs shell?

Comment: @Akira It's indeed bash, but, interestingly, `/bin/bash` rather than just `bash`. I ran `bash` within it, but it still doesn't find `coffee`.

Comment: @Etan Reisner There's the problem! `which coffee` tells me it's in `/usr/local/bin`, and `M-x term`'s `$PATH` doesn't include it! How might one add to the term path?

Comment: The question is where are you already adding that and why isn't the `M-x term` shell doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution with help from @Etan Reisner and @Akira (Thanks guys!), so I'll post it here. I'll also wait for other people who might want to expand on this answer before giving myself all the credit.

Firstly, as one may find using `which coffee`, `coffee` is located in `/usr/local/bin`. For some reason, `M-x term`'s `$PATH` doesn't include that directory, whereas terminal bash does.

We can add `/usr/local/bin` to emacs' `$PATH` by adding this line to our `.emacs`:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
```

Now, when I open up `M-x term` and run coffee, it works fine:

```
bash-3.2$ coffee
coffee>
```

However, I notice that running `M-x coffee-repl` still fails with *'no such file or directory: coffee'*. This can be fixed by adding this to `.emacs`:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```

Note that doesn't solve the problem of ugly colour escape sequences in the REPL. Ah, well, that's solved [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862471/using-node-js-with-js-comint-in-emacs). Besides, `M-x ansi-term` works *so* much better with colour.